# HEROKU - Slow initial load

Tags: heroku

My current portfolio website is hosted on Heroku and I am trying to make the initial application load faster. The biggest problem is my gatsby portfolio app and its painfully slow load. Given that I am trying to get in touch with potential recruiters, this is not an optimal situation.

I was reading about two options I am considering at this time.

1. Using `UptimeRobot` or some other website to ping my IP address periodically, since the servers/dynos are not always up and running.
2. Try with different HEROKU subscription plan in effort to remedy this issue. Currently I have $7 (HOBBY) subscription that limits me to 1 dyno.

My biggest concern is the initial load for a first time visitor as I made an attempt from another PC and the initial load was embarrassing since I am planning to use my gatsby-app for my software-developer portfolio website. This is the address `www.goran-portfolio.com`.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing slow load times. And note that hobby dynos don't sleep, so you shouldn't need to worry about waking them up.

Comment: I was not sure about dynos sleep time. Thank you for confirming it an thank you for your feedback!